# Как ограничить передвижение блока внутри окружности?

Tags: jquery

Имеется обертка в виде окружности, имеется блок внутри этой окружности. Нужно ограничить следование за курсором внутри именно окружности. Обертке задан border-radius, но сама по себе обертка ведь квадратная, поэтому внутренний блок вылезает в некоторых местах за границу.

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){ 


  wW = $('.container').width();
  wH = $('.container').height();

  var radius = wH/2;
  console.log(radius);   

  oT = $('.container').offset().top;
  oL = $('.container').offset().left;

  fW = $('.inner__block').width();
  fH = $('.inner__block').height();

  $('.container').mousemove(function(e){
    x = e.pageX-fW/2;
    y = e.pageY-fH/2;
   console.log(x,y);  

    if (x >= wW+oL-fW) {x = wW+oL-fW;};
    if (x <= oL) {x = oL;};
    if (y >= wH+oT-fH) {y = wH+oT-fH;};
    if (y <= oT) {y = oT;};

    $('.inner__block').css('top', y).css('left', x);
  });

});
```

Comment: По существу заданного вопроса можете что то сказать?

Comment: если бы Вам написали ответ на вопрос, он бы был опубликован как ответ.

Comment: и еще момент - у вас опечатка в самом вверху вопроса - *Обертке задан bordr-radius*, поправьте *bordr-radius* на *border-radius*

Comment: в принципе Ваша задача строится на вычислении углов и проверке при движении, так что вот Вам практически [такой же вопрос с решением](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/60973/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83-js-canvas). Вам нужно немного переделать решение под свою задачу.

Comment: блок квадратный или круглый?

Comment: Круглый. Круг внутри круга.

Comment: @Alex  Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky добавили, но по факту - это практически дубликат.

Comment: вы примерно это имели ввиду? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVMwWR

Comment: @Grundy да.да)именно то,что нужно. Спасибо большое. Вы не могли бы мне помочь с описанием логики Ваших действий? Что возвращает функция m и каким образом идет привязка к центру ?

Comment: @vislogurov, честно говоря уже сам забыл, сейчас попробую вспомнить

Comment: @vislogurov, и так, в общем случае - один круг находится внутри другого, если расстояние между центрами этих окружностей меньше чем разница радиусов этих окружностей. Как вы могли заметить, я сохранил точку центра большой окружности, радиус большой окружности, и рассчитываю точку цента маленькой окружности. Функция `m` вычисляет расстояние между этими центрами по формуле длины отрезка: `Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2))`. Далее просто сравниваем если текущая координата центра удалена дальше чем нужно - пропускаем, если нет - выставляем диву рассчитанное значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так, в общем случае - один круг находится внутри другого, если расстояние между центрами этих окружностей меньше чем разница радиусов этих окружностей.

Как вы могли заметить, я сохранил точку центра большой окружности,

```
center {
    x: radius,
    y: radius
}
```

где `raduis` - радиус большой окружности.

и рассчитываю точку цента маленькой окружности.
Формула довольно простая, но с нюансами, из-за того что позиционирование большой окружности идет относительно, а маленькой - абсолютно.

Сначала получаем координаты верхнего левого угла (на примере координаты Х):

```
x = e.pageX - oL - fW / 2 - 1;
```

из текущего положения курсора вычитаем смещение большой окружности, таким образом перевели координаты в значение относительно большой окружности. дальше вычитаем радиус и величину бордера. При таком значении `x` курсор мышки будет находится по центру маленькой окружности.

чтобы получить из этого координаты центра добавляем радиус и бордер, то есть фактически координаты центра маленькой окружности могут быть вычислены так

```
innerCenter {
    x: e.pageX - oL, //возможно нужно будет добавить или отнять значение ширины для более точного определения координат.
    y: e.pageT - oT
}
```

Функция m вычисляет расстояние между этими центрами по формуле длины отрезка:

[формула длины отрезка http://www.sciweavers.org/upload/Tex2Img_1448358955/render.png](http://www.sciweavers.org/upload/Tex2Img_1448358955/render.png)

```
Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2))
```

Передаем в эту функцию координаты центров окружностей и далее просто сравниваем если текущая координата центра удалена дальше чем нужно - ничего не делаем, если нет - выставляем диву рассчитанное значение координат для верхнего левого угла.

[Пример реализации на CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVMwWR)

Answer (score 1):

В принципе Ваша задача строится на вычислении углов и проверке при движении, так что вот Вам практически [такой же вопрос с решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/60973/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83-js-canvas). Вам нужно немного переделать решение под свою задачу.

P.S.: ответ опубликовали из комментариев по рекомендации модератора.

Comment: Вы меня неверно понимаете. Есть контейнер 300х300px ему border-radius задан. Но по факту контейнер остается квадратом, необходимо,чтобы внутренний блок останавливался у border, а не у края контейнера. А в Вашем примере рисуется именно круг, и границы у него, как у круга, а не как у квадрата. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OydxyM

Comment: @vislogurov Вы сами себе противоречите. В вопросе Вы указываете *Нужно ограничить следование за курсором внутри именно окружности*. В решении, которое мы Вам дали, показывается как делать подсчет границы угла. Как мы и написали, у Вас такая же задача(определение границы), только Вам нужно решение изменить под свои нужды. Не смотрите на canvas, принцип определения угла тот же.

Comment: Мне кажется задача в ссылке не дубликат, в текущей нет задачи двигаться по окружности, соответственно не нужно рассчитывать угол, достаточно проверить расстояние между центрами